# Parse user-defined #defines in g++

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I have a C++ file which is full of defines.

```
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(int (i) = (a); (i) < (b); ++(i))
// and so on
```

Is it possible to automatically create a source file in which all user-created macros are parsed and no others? `g++ -E` parses all macros, including the built-in ones.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what is a user-defined macro?

Comment: This seems a bit like an XY question, so perhaps you could tell us what you actually want to achieve. [Personally, if I found code like that in a project, I'd delete the definition, and fix up the relevant compiler errors....]

Comment: You could play games with #ifdef and #endif to group the user-defined macros and parse them but you would have to know the macro names in advance.